# can the name of a task in the timeline be different from the task title

Tags: tasks, task-list, timeline

Does anyone know if it is possible to add additional info/text to the title of a task in the timeline without having to add it to the actual task title (basically, can I modify the title of a task in the timeline)? Basically, I want tasks that are shown in the timeline to list the title of the task AND the name or initials of the person assigned to the task (which is specified in another column).

The problem I am having is that because the task title is tied to the list item and the callout, the I only way I can figure to display the task owner's initials in the timeline is by including that as part of the task title, which is not acceptable.